# How to place an image in the center of an svg element?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a `circle`, and I would like to place an `image` in the `position` that the circle is occupying. I'm trying to get the `coordinates` of the circle, to put my image there, but I don't achieve my desired result.

[image]

It is somewhat complicated to explain, but I think that with this image I make myself understood (my desired result).

[image]

I want to learn more from d3.js that is why I would like to know a way to do this dynamic, without having to set fixed values for the `x` and `y` position of my image (if my image is larger, the coordinates change, so I should be dynamic).

```js
var svg=d3.select("svg").append("g");

  svg.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("fill", "red")
  .attr("cx",100)
  .attr("cy",100);
  
   var getBoundingClientRect=d3.select("circle").node().getBoundingClientRect();
   var getBBox=d3.select("circle").node().getBBox();
  
  svg.append("svg:image")
      .attr("xlink:href", "https://www.sccpre.cat/mypng/full/57-576649_million-illnesses-twitter-round-icon-template.png")
      .attr("x", getBBox.x)
      .attr("y", getBBox.y)
      .attr("height", 40)
      .attr("width", 40)
```

```css
svg{
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<svg id="canvas"></svg>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

how can do it?

**Note: the image is a .png with transparence in the middle.**

Comment: You said that you want the calculations to be done dynamically. The only values you need for that is the image's width and height (you don't need the circle's `getBBox`, by the way). So, how are you getting those values?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado If you're right, in my real problem I can have those fixed values. excuse.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado can you answer me a short question please? I take advantage that you just answered, this has nothing to do with this question, but I don't find much information about it. Do you know if it is possible to put a white background to an image, for example in this case to the transparent part of the medium? (I know the obvious thing is to pass the image to .jpg or another format, but I'm curious) thanks.

Comment: The easiest solution without messing with the original file is just creating a white `<rect>` behind it.

Comment: Thanks! Can you remember me the answer? The user has deleted the answer.. :)

Comment: It's the centre of the circle minus half the width/height of the image.